# Firebase Firestore ver 9 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n is undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an `Orders.jsx` file -

```js
import "./Orders.css";

import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { collection, doc, getDocs, orderBy, query } from "@firebase/firestore";

import { db } from "./firebase";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";

function Orders() {
    const [{ user }] = useStateValue();
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
        console.log("User in orders: ", user);
        const myQuery = query(
            collection(db, "users", user?.uid, "orders"),
            orderBy("created", "desc")
        );

        const ordersSnapshot = await getDocs(myQuery);
        ordersSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
        });
    }, [user]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchData]);
    return (
        <div className="orders">
            <h1>Your Orders</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Orders;
```

this is the error that I get in the console and the website breaks because of it -

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n is undefined
    fromString index.esm2017.js:1028
    bc index.esm2017.js:14931
    fetchData Orders.jsx:15
    Orders Orders.jsx:27
    React 5
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 3
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:417
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:390
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:157
    js scheduler.development.js:180
    js scheduler.development.js:645
    Webpack 58
index.esm2017.js:1028
```

I read the docs of multiple documents Query [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9_4) and [`query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) method and I believe I have followed it correctly.

Also after a few seconds the console shows the required items

```js
pi_3JmvgVSDCQEtZc6S0Prn6ji3 => Object { created: 1634801251, basket: (1) […], amount: 179900 }    Orders.jsx:22
pi_3Jmvf7SDCQEtZc6S1r5tIVse => Object { amount: 329800, created: 1634801165, basket: (2) […] }    Orders.jsx:22
pi_3JmvdxSDCQEtZc6S1WLNIeec => Object { amount: 458900, created: 1634801093, basket: (2) […] }    Orders.jsx:22
pi_3JmvJ1SDCQEtZc6S0rBxmNsN => Object { amount: 6228300, basket: (5) […], created: 1634799795 }   Orders.jsx:22
```

How to fix this?

EDIT: My working solution as of now-

```js
.
.
.

try {
            if (user) {
                const myQuery = query(
                    collection(db, "users", user?.uid, "orders"),
                    orderBy("created", "desc")
                );
                // Get the snapshot which is real-time values and will update when there is a change in the DB
                const ordersSnapshot = await getDocs(myQuery);

                setOrders(
                    ordersSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                        id: doc.id,
                        data: doc.data(),
                    }))
                );
            } else {
                setOrders([]);
            }
            // ordersSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            //  console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
            // });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
        .
        .
        .
```

However I still get the error, but I just log it to the console

Comment: You're never calling `setOrders` with the data from the database.

Comment: I have not called it in this snippet but later I did.
EDIT: I put the updated snippet

Comment: Does Firebase create any related logs during this operation? Have you tried the same from another browser?

Comment: yeah I tried from different Browser but Firebase does not create any logs with error

Comment: What happened from other browser? What is the Firebase issue? I understand you are getting the query you expect and there are no logs created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So,firstly I got the same error actually I faced the same situation .

**Reason :**

So what is happening in this situation is that when you are making a fetch request from firebase your **user.uid** is undefined and that's why you are getting error "TypeError: n is undefined".

So what I have observed in your case is that you must have stored the **currentuser** in your StateProvider so that it make it accessible to the whole app and then you are importing your user from StatProvider in the Orders.jsx file to make a fetch request .

But what's actually happening is that when you are importing the user from StateProvider its actually taking time for **user.uid** to render the value ,so for few second's it render the value of **user.uid** as **undefined** then after few seconds it render the **correct value** and till the time it renders the value you have already made a fetch request from firebase with undefined uid which resulted in error .

**In order to fix this**
At the time of storing the currentuser in StateProvider just store the user.uid in the localStorage .

```
localStorage.setItem("uid",currentuser.uid);
```

And at the time of making the fetch request instead of using user.uid you can get the value of uid from localStorage which will resolve the error.

```
try {
            if (user) {
                const myQuery = query(
                    collection(db, "users", localStorage.getItem("uid"), "orders"),
                    orderBy("created", "desc")
                );
                // Get the snapshot which is real-time values and will update when there is a change in the DB
                const ordersSnapshot = await getDocs(myQuery);

                setOrders(
                    ordersSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                        id: doc.id,
                        data: doc.data(),
                    }))
                );
            } else {
                setOrders([]);
            }
            // ordersSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            //  console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
            // });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
```