# Firestore object is sometimes undefined and sometimes works fine

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am using NextJS and Firebase fairly new to both. My app is trying to collect data from firestore database on some occasions it works fine and sometimes it returns "n is undefined" refering to the firestore object "db". This happens when i call the "collection(db, "users", uid, "posts")" function in the [posts].js file. What is causing this?

Firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import {getStorage} from "firebase/storage"
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

[posts].js

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext'
import styles from '../styles/dashboard.module.css';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from '../lib/firebase';


export default function Posts(){
  const [queriedData, setQueriedData] = useState([]);
  const router = useRouter()
  const { uid } = router.query

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const postsRef = collection(db, "users", uid, "posts");
      const snapshot = await getDocs(postsRef);
      const postData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        data.id = doc.id;
        return data;
      });
      setQueriedData(postData);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  
  return(
  {queriedData.map((post) =>(<div>post.title</div>)
)}
}
```

Added await to the collection function and I also thought it was internet issues hence i setup a firebase emulator still got the same behavior.

I tried console logging "db" right after the line "export const db = getFirestore(app);". I got out "[Object Object]"

Comment: Where does the "n is undefined" error come from? Meaning which file and line is mentioned in the error message?

Comment: @KostasMinaidis it is coming from the [posts].js file on the line where i call the collection function.

Comment: Maybe console.log the db and uid variables, to see what's there and also wrap the code inside fetchData inside a try/catch and console.log the error object inside the catch for additional information about the error?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73579048/4861760

Comment: When you visit the problematic page, does it have `?uid=XXX` in the URL?

Comment: @samthecodingman yes it does but my URL is in this format "localhost:3000/XXX"

Comment: What's the full path of `[posts].js` in your project? If it is just `[posts].js` that would mean that the ID for the current page would be `router.query.posts`.

Comment: @samthecodingman the full path in the directory is ‘pages/[posts].js’ .

Comment: Add in `const { posts: uid } = router.query` and check if that solves it then.