# React.js, How to fetch the properties in a URL pathname?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to fetch the uid and token through the URL pathname using `match` in my React app. But I got error:

> Uncaught TypeError: n is undefined

and this is my code snippet:

```
const ResetPasswordConfirm = ( {match, reset_password_confirm} ) => {
    ...
    const onSubmit = e=> {
    e.preventDefault();

    const uid = match.params.uid;
    const token = match.params.token;

    reset_password_confirm(uid, token, new_password, re_new_password);
    setRequestSent(true);
    };
};
```

According to this thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609785/uncaught-typeerror-match-is-undefined#:~:text=react%2Drouter%2Ddom%20v5,render%20or%20children%20prop%20functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609785/uncaught-typeerror-match-is-undefined#:%7E:text=react%2Drouter%2Ddom%20v5,render%20or%20children%20prop%20functions).
It says it might have something to do with the version of react router, so I tried to use useParams(), but I found it hard to implement it...

I also tried to use matchPath, but I can find few examples.

Can anybody help me with this issue please?

Update:

react-router-dom version: 6.8.0

ResetPasswordConfirm is running in my container package.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reset_password_confirm } from '../actions/auth';

const ResetPasswordConfirm = ( {match, reset_password_confirm} ) => {

    const [requestSent, setRequestSent] = useState(false);
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        new_password: '',
        re_new_password: ''
    });
    
const { new_password, re_new_password } = formData;

const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

const onSubmit = e=> {
    e.preventDefault();

    const uid = match.params.uid;
    const token = match.params.token;

    reset_password_confirm(uid, token, new_password, re_new_password);
    setRequestSent(true);
};

// Is the user sending the request?
// Redirect them to the home page
if (requestSent) {
    return <Navigate to='/'/>
}

return (
  <div className="container mt-5">
    <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        {/* <div className="form-group">
            <input className="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value={email} onChange={e => onChange(e)} required></input>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <input className="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value={password} onChange={e => onChange(e)} minLength='6' required></input>
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button> */}
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input 
            type="password" 
            className="form-control" 
            id="exampleInputPassword1" 
            placeholder="New Password"
            name="new_password"
            value={new_password}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
            minLength='6'
            required></input>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input 
            type="password" 
            className="form-control" 
            id="exampleInputPassword1" 
            placeholder="Confirm New Password"
            name="re_new_password"
            value={re_new_password}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
            minLength='6'
            required></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Reset Password</button>
    </form>
  </div>  
);
};

export default connect(null, { reset_password_confirm }) (ResetPasswordConfirm);
```

Sorry for the lo-fi question. I will try to do better.

I tried to use useParams to fetch my uid

```
const onSubmit = e => {
...
let{uid} = useParams()
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue that isn't solved by following the post you linked? Where is `ResetPasswordConfirm` rendered and what version of `react-router-dom` is installed? Can you [edit] to include these details and a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: You may find this [answer](/a/59701168/8690857) helpful as well.

Comment: [Firebase Firestore ver 9 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658633)

Comment: Hi @DrewReese , thanks for your reply, sorry for my unclear question, I just edited it. I looked through this doc, https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params . But it seems that I didn't use it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no longer route props in `react-router-dom` routed components, i.e. there is not any injected `match` prop. You'll use the `useParams` hook to access the route path params in RRDv6. You can't use React hooks in nested callbacks, they must be called in the function body of a React component or in custom React hooks. Use the `useParams` hook in the component body and destructure the `uid` and `token` path params. Since you are using hooks you may as well also import and use the `useNavigate` hook and issue the navigation action at the end of the form's `onSubmit` handler instead of enqueueing a state update.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { reset_password_confirm } from '../actions/auth';

const ResetPasswordConfirm = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { uid, token } = useParams();

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    new_password: '',
    re_new_password: ''
  });
    
  const onChange = e => setFormData(formData => ({
    ...formData,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  }));

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { new_password, re_new_password } = formData;

    dispatch(reset_password_confirm(uid, token, new_password, re_new_password));
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
};

export default ResetPasswordConfirm;
```

Comment: Great thanks! `You can't use React hooks in nested callbacks, they must be called in the function body of a React component or in custom React hooks.` I will memorise this. I will also use the useNavigate for sure, thank you Drew!